# Não enviar Push para usuarios que não tenha mais o app?

Tags: android, push-notification

Tenho um painel PUSH GSM e acontece que quando usuário instala o app eu gravo o id dele para mandar notificações futuras.

Porém depois que ele desinstala eu continuo com o ID dele salvo no banco e sempre que mando executar minha rotina, ele manda o push para esses usuários mesmo sem ter o app instalado.

O problema é que já tenho milhares de id's e agora está demorando cada vez mais para o envio.

Existe a possibilidade de saber quem não tem mais o app instalado e colocar um flag no banco para que não seja mais enviado?

Exemplo do retorno do JSon:

```
{"multicast_id":5157270514039936452,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1474029083357948%0e3f0485f9fd7acv"},{"error":"MismatchSenderId"},{"message_id":"0:1474029083356778%f17b55e1f9fd7erf"}]}
```

Comment: Se estiver usando GCM pode obter resposta do status do envio da notificação. Quando a notificação falha por encontrar um usuário inexistente (app desinstalado, por exemplo), é retornado o erro `NotRegistered`. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#unreg_device. Para o APNs também existe um feedback (retorno). Quando o usuário recebe é retornado um token.

Comment: Daniel, obrigado pelo retorno, mas o GSM me retorna o seguinte Jason: {"multicast_id":5157270514039936786,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1474029083357948%0e3f0485f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"MismatchSenderId"},{"message_id":"0:1474029083356778%f17b55e1f9fd7ecd"}]}

Eu tenho o retorno de envios com sucesso e com erro.

Não tenho o retorno do Id do envio, se tivesse o retorno poderia inativar ele no meu banco de dados

Comment: Uma pergunta. Como você está conseguindo enviar as mensagens de push se você não sabe o id dos usuários?

Comment: Eu tenho todos os ids salvos no meu BD, porém no retorno não é enviado o id com sucesso ou falha.

Answer (score 0):

William, bom dia

Essa reposta que estou lhe dando é apenas lógica, pois não trabalhei com push(ainda rs)

Você disse que o retorno não vem com o ID, e nem precisa!
Você tem os Ids na hora que envia, basta montar uma rotina que monitore o envio e o status de recebimento.

Se você enviou para o dispositivo XXX999, você não precisa que esse ID seja retornado pois você ja sabe para quem enviou, basta monitorar o status!

Comment: Boa Tarde, Lucas 
O problema é que o envio é feito em lotes de 1000 registros.
Se fosse envio de 1 para 1 conseguiria ter o retorno, mas com 1000 registro e sem o retorno dos ids fica difícil identificar.

Comment: Esse numero de registros por lotes é parametrizável?

Comment: Não, Lucas eu só recebo um ID